# How can I create a bootable SD card with linux kernel?

Tags: linux, bootloader, arm

I just order an ARM Cortex A8 development board with preinstalled Android, but instead of the preinstalled OS I would like to use Linux, so I compiled the kernel with success, but I don't know how can I create a bootable SD card with the Linux OS. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simplified way would be to use Puppy: http://bkhome.org/arm/rp-hardware-setup.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ive never worked with the ARM Cortex A8, but I would assume that it shouldn't be too hard.

[Google rendered the following](http://www.yoctoproject.org/download/bsp/texas-instruments-arm-cortex-a8-development-board-beagleboard)